# Efficient method to check for matching files in Java

Tags: java, file, filenames, processing-efficiency

I'm no Java expert but the program I'm making is going to be dealing with high throughput.  So I thought I'd do a little crowd sourcing for opinions.  Here's the situation.

A java process will be watching a directory for files to process, these files will be paired (data file to be stored and xml file with meta information to be cataloged).  So I need to get the list of current files, check for the required twins, and then process.

Files will always have matching filenames and only differ by file extension e.g.
filename1.jpg
filename1.xml
filename2.jpg
filename2.xml

I have three options I've thought of so far.

1. Use FilenameFilter with File.List(FileNamefilter) call to check if the total files with a filename is greater than 1.
2. Use two filenamefilters to generate a list of files with .xml and without .xml, convert the non XML file list to an ArrayList and call Collections.binarySearch().
3. Generate a list of all files without .xml extension, use this list as the keys for a hashmap of key/value pairs that assumes the .xml file based on the filename.  Then run through the hash list and check for the existence of the .xml twin before processing.

Any thoughts?

EDITS/COMMENTS

After looking at the suggestions and tinkering I'm for now going with using two FilenameFilters, one that lists XML files and one that does not.  The list of XML files is stripped of the xml extension and dumped into a hash.  Then the list of data files is iterated through, calling hashlist.contains() to see if a match exists in the hashset before proceeding.

There is the concern as mentioned below of processing incomplete files.  As I said in comments, I assume that a newly written file is not visible to non-writing processes until that write is complete (new files, not open for edit)

Answer (score 3):

Get all files, **sort** them, then run a linear pass over the files names and see which agree on the prefix. Obviously, they should come right next to each other in the sorted list.

That should be a lot simpler and faster than the filter and hashmaps!

To monitor the directory, you might want to use notification base APIs such as inotify when available. Then the OS will signal when the folder contents have changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly off topic, but I hope sufficiently relevant to post here, given the intentions stated.

The question doesn't state how files arrive in the directory.  If they're coming in across a network or the internet, or streamed from another process, delivery may be less than instantaneous, leading to a risk of selecting and processing a file that is not yet fully delivered, e.g. half of a jpeg file.

If you have high throughput, then if you allow it, this is a situation that will happen. Even if you briefly delay before processing, it will probably still somehow manage to happen sooner or later.

A common strategy for dealing with this is to deliver to an intermediate filename (or better still, an adjacent folder).  When delivery is done, the delivering process would rename or move the file to its correct name and location.  This move is effectively instant (atomic).  In the case of ftp, at least one well known tool performs these steps automatically.

Its perhaps on-topic to mention that if your partially delivered file is in the same folder, renamed with just an alternate file extension, this could have a bearing on some of the options mentioned for this question.

Comment: I was under the assumption that since these files are being written new the OS will not show the file as existing until the writing is done.  That is while a copy/write is happening on a NEW file in a directory, any processes not performing that write cannot see it when they query the directory for it's current files.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually any OS I know will start showing the file when it is created, not when it is closed (finished writing). Which is why it is a best practise to write to temp files (or temp folders), then move the file to the final name when done.